# Form size corrupted when working on two monitors

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have 20 UserForms in a PowerPoint VBA project.

I usually work with the VBE window open on a large monitor connected to my laptop.

All of the forms have just rescaled to 80% of their original height - plus everything inside them. For example, doing a diff between forms I have exported shows one form to have gone from ClientHeight = 2316 to ClientHeight = 1848.

**Notes**

- I had not been doing any work on the UserForm design
- The only way these forms had been touched was to add a one line comment to each of them (just opening the code window)
- This has happened before. Usually re-opening the presentation on the laptop monitor, running the form, and saving and closing from there restores the original sizing - but not in this case
- ClientHeight is not the same as the "Height" property of a form. I assume all measurements on a form are scaled from ClientHeight and ClientWidth (no other properties have changed - yet everything is scaled ... and looks awful)

Any suggestions for getting my forms back to their original sizing?

**Options I am thinking of:**

- Re-import forms exported earlier - but that's a lot of work to do
- Restore ClientHeights via VBA - is there a way of accessing ClientHeight/ClientWidth from VBA and updating their values before saving?

A long term solution to prevent this happening again would be to only work in the laptop window and not on the other monitor - which isn't ideal! Any other suggestions?

**Thoughts about a possible repair strategy**

- The height and width properties of the form don't appear to change when a form gets corrupted
- The ratio of the ClientHeight to Height (and/or ClientWidth to Width) could be stored
- Scan the forms to check this ratio, and if it's out, export the form, change the ClientHeight/ClientWidth values to restore the ratio and import back in

The relationship between these values doesn't seem to be quite a simple ratio:
[image: Dimension ratios for three userforms]

So just relying on that might not work.

Comment: Are the 2 monitors different resolutions? If so, that's why.

Comment: The monitor is 1920x1200 and the laptop screen is 1920x1080 so the height of the laptop is 0.9 the height of the monitor (not 0.8). The laptop screen is scaled to 125% and the attached monitor to 100% - 100%/125% = 0.8 - which is the change I am seeing in the form heights (but not widths). Do I need to adjust the scaling/resolution for the convenience of the VBE and the inconvenience of everything else?

Comment: Yes. The VBE is quite old software, written before multiple monitors became commonplace.